# How can I query for obsolete/outdated installed packages (ebuilds) on Gentoo?

Tags: package-management, gentoo

Installed packages sometimes become obsolete because the package got version bumped and the ebuild for the old version got dropped. Also it happens that packages are dropped completely from the tree (usually for a good reason). I'd like to query those packages in order to take the appropriate action (update, remove).

**How to query installed packages** that

1. have no ebuild for the current installed version; and
2. have no ebuild at all anymore (e.g. because it got deleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer that came up so far is

```
TEST_FOR_REDUNDANCY=false eix -T
```

<sup>[source](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-944496.html#top)</sup>

It shows a little bit more then I asked for, but it's a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

For this you can use `eix-test-obsolete` from `app-portage/eix`. `eix-test-obsolete` is set of few tests to check is package is obsolete.

I output packages are grouped by specific test. One of them is "Installed packages with a version not in the database (or masked)". Description of all of them you can find in `man eix`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `eix-test-obsolete` is a great tool, but I think what I really want are the `eix` parameters that lists all packages that fall into 1. or 2.

Comment: I don't know if you can be that specific. You can also check `TEST_` and `NONEXISTENT_IF_` variables in `man eix`.

Comment: Of course, any other tool besides `eix` that does the job is also ok.